# Service not getting started

Tags: android, service

I am writing my first service. My activity works well, but when I call my service, it doesn't.

It looks like it's `onCreate()` is not getting called.

My service code:

```
public class NeglectedService extends Service {
    public static final String MY_SERVICE = "android.intent.action.MAIN";
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service onCreate...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am not even getting the Toast message.

Here is my activity

```
startService(new Intent(NeglectedService.MY_SERVICE));
```

My manifest

```
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you enter something like

```
<service android:name=".subpackagename.ServiceName"/>
```

into your Android Manifest xml file?

Comment: erm, no. I will check where such is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as the `NeglectedService.MY_SERVICE` is just a string, in your `startService` call you're essentially calling:

```
startService(new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"));
```

Clearly that doesn't have any reference to your particular service and isn't what you want. Instead, either register the service for particular intent filters and include those in your intent, or call it by class:

```
startService(new Intent(this, NeglectedService.class));
```

Comment: Thanks Kabuko
I made this change, but still, it doesn't look like the service starts.
How ever, it does make more sense to make the call like you wrote.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems I had 2 main problems. yours also helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Call your Service using an Explicit intent, instead of using an implicit action string, which should be more unique anyway.  In other words, use this in your Activity code:

```
startService( new Intent(this, NeglectedService.class) );
```

Hope that helps!